# get metric size of image in cpp

Tags: c++, image, size, metrics

I want to read the metric sizes from an image in C++. In Octave I could do this up to now:

```
IM.info = imfinfo(path_to_image);
IM.info.ResolutionUnit
IM.info.XResolution
IM.info.YResolution
```

For example, when I export a PNG on Inkscape, I specify DPI and the pixel size of the image. So this information should be available in the metadata right? I find many examples of how to read the pixel sizes, but none that can read metric information. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I recommend adding the library you are using to read the png file to the question

Comment: Until now I was using opencv. But as I thought, that is not possible there. -> I hope I'm wrong. I am open for new libraries. As long as I can solve the problem.

Comment: Rats. I don't think OpenCV can't get you that info because it doesn't care. When it reads it's just after the matrix.

Comment: https://answers.opencv.org/question/85615/opencv-image-dpi/

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard library does not have functions for reading PNG files. You will need to parse the file.

According to [the specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter11.html) Chapter 11. PNG Options and Extensions, the relevant chunk should be Physical Pixel Dimensions (pHYs).